# How to can I develop a programming language like Coffee Script?

Tags: programming-languages

What are the initial requirement that i need to know to develop a programming language like coffee script that basically has its own syntax but after compilation changes into another language. I did Google on that but couldn't find the right answer.

Comment: I'll try not to sound like an arroguant asshole but the fact you're asking probably means you shoudln't start such an adventure now. This warning being made, I hope other people than me will be able to provide links to introductory material.

Comment: Maybe you could start by making sure you understand how the coffeescript compiler works ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Specify your language with a basic [formal grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar) in something like [EBNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form).

  ```
  statement        = if-statement
                   | return-statement
                   | expression
                   | ...

  if-statement     = "if" "(" expression ")" "{" statements "}"

  return-statement = "return" expression ";"

  ...
  ```
- Learn about simple [parsing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) by [recursive descent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) and [operator precedence](http://effbot.org/zone/simple-top-down-parsing.htm).
- Write a parser that creates an [abstract syntax tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) from a source file.
- Write a [code generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_generation_%28compiler%29) that converts this AST into your target language; or
- Write an [interpreter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_%28computing%29) that merely evaluates the AST.

Comment: +1 for Pratt parsers, they're the single most awesome parsing algorithm IMHO.

Comment: @delnan: They are pretty great.

Answer (score 3):

A good first step is to read [Programming Languages: Application and Interpretation](http://www.cs.brown.edu/~sk/Publications/Books/ProgLangs/). It'll teach you how to design and implement languages with interpreters.

Answer (score 0):

The initial requirements are:

- Determine the target computer language
- Develop the syntax of your new language
- Map the syntax of your new language to the target language.

You'll still have plenty of work ahead, but basically, you're translating your new language into a target language.